# Launch Sharepoint workfloweach time a change is made, even if there is a pause

Tags: sharepoint, email, workflow

I have a workflow on a Sharepoint list which sends an email alert based on a date field in the list item - this requires using the "pause until" option.  This seems to lock the "on change" workflow from being fired again if another change is made during the period of the pause.  Is there some way around this?

Some details, since maybe I'm missing something a little more basic:

The list item contains an "end date" field, and I need to send an alert 3 days before this date as a reminder.  So, if the user changes the end date (launching the workflow) and then changes the date again during the pause period the email date won't be updated if the workflow doesn't start up again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a second workflow that just addresses the OnChange behavior and then use the **Stop Workflow** action, use the **Start Workflow** action (that will read the new date and work properly).

Comment: That's a lot simpler than I would have expected.  Thanks!