# Re-running or stopping one workflow with another in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, workflow

I'm working with a list in Sharepoint 2010. When an item is created a workflow is kicked off that will pause until a specified date and then send off a reminder email.

The problem is that if a user edits an item, the paused workflow doesn't re-start.  I've tried creating a second workflow that runs "On Change" to stop or re-run the paused workflow. But it seems I can't stop a different workflow, and can't restart the other workflow if it's already paused. Is there any solution for this I'm overlooking?

I saw this: [Launch Sharepoint workfloweach time a change is made, even if there is a pause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890547/launch-sharepoint-workfloweach-time-a-change-is-made-even-if-there-is-a-pause)
but it didn't work for me. Maybe something is different in SP2010?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Consider redesigning your application: for such tasks you should use [timer jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spjobdefinition.aspx). Your timer job would query the list for all items changed before date X / before X days and the send emails for all results. It's not a good idea to misuse workflow for a generally non-workflow task.